# Get value and line number for non unique parameters in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to check the csv file for uniqueness of all values in each column and get the number of the row where the nonunique parameter is located and its value. Example file

```
Vendor,Email,Country
Nick,nick@gmail.com,US
Joe,joe@gmail.com,NL
Nick,nk@gmail.com,GB
Mary,nk@gmail.com,AU
```

Expected result

```
name = [{'Nick':3},]
email = [{'nk@gmail.com':4},]
```

or something like that, this output format is optional

All I was able to do was pass the uniqueness test. I did it in two ways.

**1.Using python csv library**

```
with open(file) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    # Check uniques vendor name and email in file without request to DB
    vendor_list = []
    email_list = []
    for count, rows in enumerate(reader, 1):
        vendor_list.append(rows['Vendor'])
        email_list.append(rows['Email'])
    vendor_unique = set(vendor_list)
    email_unique = set(email_list)
    if len(vendor_list) != len(vendor_unique) or len(email_list) != len(email_unique):
        raise ParseError('Your name and email should be unique')
```

**2. Using pandas**

```
import pandas as pd
record = pd.read_csv(file)
if ((len(record['Email'])) != (len(record['Email'].unique())):
    raise ParseError('Your email should be unique')
elif (len(record['Vendor']) != len(record['Vendor'].unique())):
    raise ParseError('Your name should be unique')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas solution - get duplicated values (all without first by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html)), filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and last swap key, values in output dicts:

```
name = {v: k + 1 for k, v in df.loc[df['Vendor'].duplicated(), 'Vendor'].items()}
print (name)
{'Nick': 3}

email = {v: k +1 for k, v in df.loc[df['Email'].duplicated(), 'Email'].items()}
print (email )
{'nk@gmail.com': 4}
```

Comment: Is it possible to exclude empty values from the search? Now if the file doesn't have a value set (empty value), I get  `{nan: 3}`.

Comment: Use `name = {v: k + 1 for k, v in df.loc[df['Vendor'].duplicated() & df['Vendor'].notna(), 'Vendor'].items()}`